# passing array fields to jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form I am submitting via jquery ajax.  Early in the form, I have this field:

```
 <select name="inquirymodule[]" id="inquirymodule">
```

The user can add as many as they like, and all the selects go into the inquirymodule[] array.

The jQuery looks like this:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'ajax.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
                inquirymodule: jQuery("select[name='inquirymodule[]']").serialize(),
         },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert('error');
         }
 });
```

That works fine.

Trying to do the same thing with a date, like this:

```
 <input class="formInput" type="text" id="startBreak0" name='startbreak[]' />
```

adding

```
 startbreak: jQuery("select[name='startbreak[]']").serialize()
```

to the ajax call.  It doesn't work, I cannot see why.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have `select` in the selector, when the elements are inputs

```
startbreak: jQuery("input[name='startbreak[]']").serialize()
```